# Error: Timeout of 40000ms exceeded

Tags: solidity, hardhat, chai

I'm running a test using hardhat and chai. I keep getting this error:

Error: Timeout of 40000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/mnt/c/Users/hp/Documents/SolidityProj/general/test/faucetTest.js)

This is the test code:

```
const { loadFixture } = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers");
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("Faucet", function () {
  async function deployContractAndSetVariables() {
    const Faucet = await ethers.getContractFactory("Faucet");
    const faucet = await Faucet.deploy();

    const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

    console.log("Signer 1 address: ", owner.address);
    return { faucet, owner };
  }

  it("should deploy and set the owner correctly", async function () {
    const { faucet, owner } = await loadFixture(deployContractAndSetVariables);

    expect(await faucet.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
  });
});
```

This is my hardhat.config file:

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your hardhat.config file:

```
mocha: {
    timeout: 100000000,
  },
```

Like so:

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
  mocha: {
    timeout: 100000000,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it

The first one is by changing the hardhat.config file

```
mocha: {
    timeout: 100000000,
  }
```

The Second one is by giving a timeout at the end of the function as follows

```
it("...", async function () {
...
}).timeout(100000);
```

Good Luck